# WooCommerce Add Fee If Coupon Applied

Tags: woocommerce, coupon, fee

I'd like to be able to add a fixed $20 fee if a given coupon code (100% off) is applied to the cart. The fee should also not have taxes applied.  I'm offering a try at home service for $20, so a certain coupon would discount the cart and all products by 100% but add a $20 fixed fee.  Any help is much appreciated!

JC

Comment: For your information fee lines in Woocommerce are always added by default below shipping lines and there is no other way when adding a fee to Woocommerce. You can change that behavior only if you customize the related templates *(which is another question)*.

Comment: That would be great but the code your provided added $20 to the Shipping line not a Fee line.

Comment: Sorry but I am using [`WC_Cart` `add_fee()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee) method, which adds a FEE and NOT a SHIPPING METHOD… There is no other ways or methods to add a fee. The display problem that you have is due to your theme, a customization that you have made or a third party plugin. But it's not due to my code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will apply a fee of `$20` if a specific coupon code has been applied to cart:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','conditional_custom_fee', 10, 1 );
function conditional_custom_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE set your targeted coupon code (100 % off)
    $coupon_code = 'thatsforfree';

    // Check if our targeted coupon is applied
    if( in_array( wc_format_coupon_code( $coupon_code ), $cart->get_applied_coupons() ) ){
        $title = __('Fee', 'woocommerce'); // The fee title
        $cost  = 20; // The fee amount

        // Adding the fee (not taxable)
        $cart->add_fee( $title, $cost, false );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

**The display in cart and checkout pages** *(on Woocommerce storefront theme)*:

[image]

> This code uses The Woocommerce FEE API using [`WC_Cart` method `add_fee()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee) with the dedicated action hook `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response!  The code is adding a $20 fee, however, it is adding it on the Shipping line as a Flat Rate.  Is there a way to make this show as a separate line with the fee title?  Thanks!

Comment: So there is no way to create a new line?  This will give customers the impression they are paying for shipping, when shipping is to be free.  A bit confusing.  Any workarounds for a new line?  Thanks!

Comment: I would accept the answer, but this code did not result in what I wanted.  It added the fee in the shipping line.

Comment: @loictheaztec is there a way to add a css script to your PHP? Your solution works perfectly for me, but I'd like to use CSS to hide the default shipping options when your code runs. Thanks